# Nested helpers in handlebars (execution order)

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

I have two registered helpers: "_i" for translating ui strings and "pluralize" to pluralize strings. I often have them nested, like here:

```
{{#_i}}{{num_hidden}} hidden {{#pluralize}}comment,comments,{{num_hidden}}{{/pluralize}}{{/_i}}
```

(This will result in things like "5 hidden comments").

The way the UI string translation works by looking up the entire string within the _i tags in a dictionary and then replacing it, e.g. for Spanish:

```
{{num_hidden}} {{#pluralize}}comentario escondido,comentarios escondidos,{{num_hidden}}{{/pluralize}}
```

Then I would run the pluralize helper on this string. This worked well with mustache when we dynamically extended the view before the call to mustache. However with Handlebars helpers it first executes the pluralize helper (inner-most) and then I get a UI string for which there is no translation.

I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you considered completely revamping your translation strategy? [Pluralization isn't nearly that simple](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Hogan.js instead of Handlebars because it has better compatibility with mustache and mustache lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead nesting you can use one helper and MessageFormat.js library: https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js - It allows to show 'messages' in different languages including plural and gender rules.

Here is handlebar helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function (text) {
    var options,
        compiledText;

    options  = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

    if (compiled[locale].hasOwnProperty(text)) {
        compiledText = compiled[locale][text];
    } else {
        compiledText = mf.compile(dictionary[locale][text]);
        compiled[locale][text] = compiledText;
    }

    return compiledText(options.hash);
});
```

The `dictonary` object is one with all the translations:

```
dictionary = {
    en: {
        "You have MESSAGES_COUNT messages": "You have {MESSAGE_COUNT, plural, one {1 message} other {# messages}}",
    },
    pl: {
        "You have MESSAGES_COUNT messages": "Masz {MESSAGE_COUNT, plural, one {1 wiadomość} other {# wiadomości}}"
    }
};
```

and `compiled` object is one that stores cached versions of 'messages' to not compile it every time it's used. You can also compile 'messages' in build time.